# Getting all the Properties on tab in umbraco

Tags: c#, user-controls, umbraco

I'm trying to figure out the umbraco API here. In a piece of code, I'm trying to list all Properties on a Tab. I know I can get these by using:

```
 MyTab.PropertyTypes
```

But this property is declared "obsolete" (deprecated) and it refers me to the function GetPropertyTypes(int). This function, however, requires a parameter 'ContentTypeId' and I'm not sure what I should specify. I want all the properties, not only properties of a certain type.

I've tried looking for the documentation about this function, but couldn't find any. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps:

```
DocumentType dt = new DocumentType(1051); //id of documenttype
        foreach (ContentType.Tab x in dt.getVirtualTabs)
        {
            List<PropertyType> Properties = x.GetAllPropertyTypes();

            foreach (var propertyType in Properties)
            {
                propertyType.Name;
            }      
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I don't know how I missed that. I was looking for a method "GetAllProperties()" and I guess I thought PropertyTypes were something different altogether.

Comment: @user1816487, if this answer solved your problem, you should consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: in visual studio, while typing a method, the returned object, in this case a List<PropertyType>, is listet. Or hover the mouse over x.GetAllPropertyTypes and u can see the what is returned